# Show $f(x) = |x|^p$ is differentiable at $0$ for $p > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Show $f(x) = |x|^p$ is differentiable at $0$ for $p > 1$.

*My proof is below.  My question is to verify or improve it, or respond to the remark.*

**Proof:** We examine the limit from both the right and left:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {h^p - 0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} h^{p-1} = 0
\end{align}$$
since $p - 1 > 0$.  Likewise,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {(-h)^p - 0}{-(-h)} = - \lim_{h \to 0^-} (-h)^{p-1} = 0
\end{align}.$$

Since the limits from both sides are equal, the limit is defined.  QED.

**Remark:** At $0$, the error from the linear approximation of $f$ for a small step $h$ is $h^{p-1}$ which for $p \in (1,2)$ is only "slightly smaller" then $h$ itself, but still close enough to make the function differentiable.

Comment: This works becaue $p - 1 > 0$.  Well done.

Comment: For the argument to work it would enough to have a function $f$ which is continuous at $x=0$ and such that $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(x) }{x} =0. $$ In this case, one gets $$ f'(0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} =0.$$ So, yes, that bit of additional decay you get from $p>1$ makes all the difference.